# form_for submit button does not work for ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, submit, form-for

my form_for submit button only works partially; the data is saved in the database but the redirection fails. Here are the relevant codes for the form:

```
app/views/orders/new.html.erb

<h1>Menu</h1>
<%= link_to "Back to channel", current_channel_path %>
<div class="container">
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Meal</th>
        <th>Price</th>
     </tr>        
   </thead>
<tbody>
  <% @menu_items.each do |t| %>
  <p>
    <tr>
      <td><%= t.name %></td>
      <td><%= number_to_currency(t.price) %></td>

      <%= form_for (@order), url: orders_path, remote: true do |f| %>
      <td><%= f.number_field :quantity, value: 1, class: "form-control", min: 1 %></td>
      <%= f.hidden_field :meal, :value => t.name %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :unit_price, :value => t.price %>

      <td><%= f.submit "Order", class: "btn btn-primary" %></td>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  </p>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
</div>
```

Here are the codes for routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
#For Orders
get 'orders' => 'orders#new'
post 'orders' => 'orders#create'
get 'all_orders' => 'orders#show'

resources :users
resources :orders
```

Here are the relevant codes for orders

```
def new
  @menu_items = MenuItem.all
  @order = Order.new
end

def create 
  @order = current_channel.orders.build(order_params)
  @order.user = current_user

  if @order.save 
    flash.now[:success] = "Order has been recorded!"
    redirect_to all_orders_path
  else 
    flash.now[:danger] = "Order was not recorded!"
    render 'new'
  end 
end
```

I read that the submit button may not work as it is nested in the table. I have tried putting the form outside of the table but the submit still does not redirect; the submit button however creates the record in the orders database in both cases. Any idea why this is the case? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What do you mean by redirection fails?

Comment: you are making ajax request. you need create.js.erb file not redirection.

Comment: The error message would help to diagnose

Comment: @Pavan by redirection fails, i mean that i dont get redirected to the correct page after i click the submit buttom but the data is recorded in the database.

Comment: To which you want to be redirected to?

Comment: I want to be redirected to a settings page. I'm quite sure the problem doesn't lie with the page since i have tried redirection to other pages. There are not error messages, the development log shows that the pages were rendered correctly.

Comment: Can you post your routes in the question?

Comment: Okay, posted, changed the settings path to the original all_orders path

Comment: So now the page is not redirected to `all_orders_path`?

Comment: yea, it is not, it just records down the order in the database

Answer (score 1):

You need a route set for the index path which isn't listed above. If you're following standard crud conventions you should just use "`resources :orders`" in your routes files which will generate the post/put/delete/get routing you need. Then your redirection will work.

Comment: I did put resource :orders in my routes files, but it doesnt work.

Comment: It must be "resources :orders".  Notice resources is plural.  Also, you must move this route above the others you manually created since rails looks for the first matching route and executes.  Lastly, in your controller you must change the redirect_to "path" to:  redirect_to order_path(:id) .  If you want to see all orders and not just the one you created you should redirect to orders_path